# Why navbar links are not appearing in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, web, navbar, bootstrap-5

This is the code I have written in React for a Navbar...I have used React-Bootstrap

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const MyNavBar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/">
          <img
            src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/606/489/original/vector-letter-a-logo-slice-logo-design-concept-template.jpg"
            width="30"
            height="30"
            className="d-inline-block align-top"
            alt="logo"
          />
          Aritra Debnath
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink exact to="/projects" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Projects</NavLink>
            <NavLink exact to="/contact" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Contact</NavLink>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Toggle>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default MyNavBar;
```

Everything looks perfect but for some reason The NavLinks are not appearing in the Browser...
[Here is the Browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMCrx.png)
Please Help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The Navbar.Toggle should wrap around the Nav component, not be placed inside it.

```
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
<Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="me-auto">
        <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="/projects" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Projects</NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="/contact" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Contact</NavLink>
      </Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```

If that's not the problem, it could also be in the part where you call the MyNavBar component or maybe in the CSS.
Also make sure you close your App in BrowserRouter:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```